# Share data between two google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've two sheets named "Production" & "Quality". I'm looking for a script that can pull the data referring to two columns (A & B) in the "Production" sheet and if the value is not available in the "Quality" sheet, the script should pull the row to the "Quality" sheet at the end automatically and it should be editable in "Quality" sheet.

Thanks and Regards,
JK

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Answer (score 0):

1-On your computer, go to docs.google.com/spreadsheets/.

2-Open or create a sheet.

3-Select a cell.

4-Type = followed by the sheet name, an exclamation point, and the cell being copied. For example, =Sheet1!A1 or ='Sheet number two'!B4.

Note: If a sheet name contains spaces or other non-alphanumeric symbols, include single quotes around it (as in the second example).